# C# property definition

Tags: c#

For C# properties, I can do this:

```
public class Employee{

 public string Name { get; private set; }

 public Employee(string name){
  Name = name;
 }

}
```

which means that the Name property can be set within the class Employee & can be read publicly.

But, if I want to restrict the set to only within the constructors of the Employee class, I need to do:

```
public class Employee{
 public readonly string Name = String.Empty;
 public Employee(string name){
  Name = name;
 }
}
```

But, for this case, I had to change the property to a field.

Is there any reason this is not possible/allowed in C#:

```
public class Employee{
 public string Name { get; private readonly set; }
 public Employee(string name){
  Name = name;
 }
}
```

IMO this will allow us to have properties which can be set only in the constructor & does not require us to change properties to fields...

Thanks!

Comment: I guess 'readonly set' does not make sense, but you get the picture :)

Comment: What you're looking for is something syntactic which combines auto-properties and immutability as readonly would give you.  That doesn't exist as of C# 4.0.  I would back you if you wanted to open that up as a feature enhancement for a future version.

Comment: There should be a "constructor set" variant on properties, especially since it's a place where they could really shine (simplifying initialization with a specific configuration)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
private readonly string name = Empty.String;
public string Name { get { return name; } }
```

Comment: @Danvil - you are right about this code & this is what I had ended up with. Was wondering if we could do it with a single property instead of having an additional private readonly property...

Comment: Also with the "Auto"-Property notation you can not have a default initalizer. To be truely complete, it would get messy with something like `public string Name { get; private readonly set = Empty.String; }` ...

Comment: @Sunny: There is no additional private *property* - there is a private *field*. And this is just equivalent to the field, the compiler would have created as a hidden field, if one would have used an auto property.

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with:

```
public class Employee
{

 private string nameField;
 public string Name 
 { 
  get
  {
    return this.nameField;
  }
 }
 public Employee(string name)
 {
   this.nameField = name;
 }
```

Comment: Mark the private member variable as readonly and you'll have what he's looking for semantically.  However, he'd like something syntactically that combines auto-properties and immutability as readonly would give you.  Unfortunately, C# does not have that yet.

Comment: Absolutely nothing at all, i'm wondering what the hell everyone is doing two.

Answer (score 1):

readonly applies to variables and not to methods. `set` is converted into a method by the compiler, and therefore the `readonly` attribute makes no sense.

In order to accomplish what you want you need.

```
public class Employee
{
   private readonly string _name;

   public string Name
   { 
      get
      {
         return _name;
      }
   }

   public Employee(string name)
   {
      _name = name;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned with only setting the properties within the constructor of the class that you're currently within, just make it a property with a private setter and don't set it in the class.. it's not like you don't have control over that situation.

$0.02

Comment: It's not just that you should only set it from the constructor, apparently the compiler may use extra optimizations for readonly fields that it can't do for regular properties even with private setters.

Comment: I agree, that since this is limited to within the class I do have all the control. Just was wondering if there was any reason not to support the keyword on the set.

Answer (score 0):

You can have

```
public class Employee{
 public string Name { get; private set; }
 public Employee(string name){
  Name = name;
 }
}
```

Which will make a readonly public property. If you think about it, having a private readonly setter on a public property doesn't really make sense because you're wanting the setter to be readonly which is a method, not a variable.

If you were to make the setter readonly, essentially what you're doing is denying any access whatsoever to setting the value of the property. This is why you need the backing field.

Comment: There is a difference between `private` and `readonly`! Your code will not create a readonly property but a property which has a private setter. It can still be changed from inside the class.

Comment: @Danvil I agree, what I'm saying is that it doesn't make sense to have a readonly setter because it's a method.